# Как выполнить группировку по часам с шагом в 2 часа в postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица:

[image: Есть таблица:]

С помощью запроса:

```
select to_char(date_trunc('hour', date_and_time), 'hh24:mi') as onehour, count(*) 
from authorizations 
where to_char(date_and_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2021-04-01' 
group by onehour
```

формирую сгруппированное по часам количество запросов:

[image: группировка по часам]

ВОПРОС. Как сделать так, чтобы вывод происходил с шагом не в 1 час как у меня, а в 2 часа или 3 часа и т.д?
Например, если шаг в 2 часа, то запросы где 8 и 9 часов будут в одной группе и в count будет 3. **Часы, которых не было в первой таблице должны пропускаться, так же как и в моём решении.**

Помогите пожалуйста знатоки postgresql.

Comment: generate_series с нужным шагом как опорная таблица, и join к ней данных из таблицы.

Comment: Думал об этом варианте, но больше интересует есть ли возможность без объединений а чисто группировкой?

Comment: Перевести в TIMESTAMP, поделить на 2 часа (7200 секунд), группировать по целочисленному частному.

Comment: спасибо за наводку, работает